# How to make two Lists in one View scroll as one page in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to add two tables with different sizes to one view in SwiftUI. I want both tables be fully expanded and the whole view to scroll as one. For now I only get both tables fixed size and scroll separately.

```
some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Table foo")
        List(foo { item in Text(item.name) })

        Text("Table bar")
        List(bar { item in Text(item.name) })
    }
}
```

Tried changing `VStack` to a `ScrollView`, it makes things even worse - tables are becoming one liners.

Also tried replacing `List()` with `ForEach()` but then I lose features of the `List()` I actually want.

Comment: The thing you are looking for is not two different lists! it's a collectionView with a custom waterfall layout. You can use UIKit for that

Answer (score 11):

I think you want one List with multiple ForEach's.  Optionally, you could make it a grouped List with multiple sections.  Adapted for your sample, the following concept has worked well for me on several occasions:

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Table foo"))
            {
                ForEach(foo) { item in Text(item.name) }
            }
            Section(header: Text("Table bar"))
            {
                ForEach(bar) { item in Text(item.name) }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Form` to embed two lists in a scroll view.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form .